# css file not functioning properly in IE9 and earlier

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a functioning website for a family run business. It is working well in Chrome, FF, Safari, Opera and IE10 & 11, but not in IE9 and earlier.  Not all divs are being displayed in IE 9 (the #logo, #logo_text, #nav and #pic_box divs to be precise). This only occurred when I tried to wrap the whole website in a #container div and used a #header div which were required to make the web page work great in Chrome et al.

I have been trying to find a solution for a couple of days now. The problem appears to be either with my #container div or the #header div or #main_content div as the problem #divs were displaying before I introduced these 'wrappers'.

Your help much appreciated.  Let me know if you need more info.

CSS as follows

```
    html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}



a {
    color: #464544;
}
a:hover {
    color: #9e9e9e;
}


body {
background-color: #f1f1f1;

background: #f1f1f1; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f1f1f1 0%, #ededed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f1f1f1), color-stop(100%,#ededed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f1f1f1 0%,#ededed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f1f1f1 0%,#ededed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f1f1f1 0%,#ededed 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #f1f1f1 0%,#ededed 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f1f1f1', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

}


/** container **/
#container {

  position: relative; 
  float: none; 
  height: auto;
  width: 1100px;

  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}


#header {

  position: relative; 
  float: none; 
  height: 140px;    
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  clear:both;
}



/** logo **/
#logo {
  float:left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px; 

}



/** logo text (contact details)**/

#logo_text {

  display:inline;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#logo_text p {
  color: #464544;
  font-family: Verdana; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-style: normal; 
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 0.8em;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
  text-decoration: none;
  }


/** Nav Bar **/

#nav {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 160px;
  clear:both;


}
#nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  font-family: verdana; 
  font-weight: normal; 
  font-style: normal; 
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #464544;
}
#nav a {
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #464544;
  border-top: 8px solid #464544;
}
#nav a:active {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #464544;
  border-top: 8px solid #464544;
}




/** Main body Picture Box **/

#pic_box {

float:left; display:inline;

width: 228px;
height: 476px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
border:3px solid #696969;

-webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 6px 6px 6px;
-moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 6px 6px 6px; 
box-shadow: #B3B3B3 9px 9px 9px;


background: #f3f3f3; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FAADAB 0%, #E8A09E 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FAADAB), color-stop(100%,#E8A09E)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #FAADAB 0%,#E8A09E 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #FAADAB 0%,#E8A09E 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #FAADAB 0%,#E8A09E 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #FAADAB 0%,#E8A09E 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FAADAB', endColorstr='#E8A09E',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */


margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 12px;
overflow:hidden;
}



/** Main body Welcome Box **/

#welcome_box {

float:left; display:inline;

width: 358px;
height: 436px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
border:3px solid #696969;

-webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 6px 6px 6px;
-moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 6px 6px 6px; 
box-shadow: #B3B3B3 9px 9px 9px;


background: #CDCF6D; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #E6E87A 0%, #CDCF6D 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#E6E87A), color-stop(100%,#CDCF6D)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #E6E87A 0%,#CDCF6D 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #E6E87A 0%,#CDCF6D 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #E6E87A 0%,#CDCF6D 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #E6E87A 0%,#CDCF6D 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f3f3f3', endColorstr='#CDCF6D',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */



margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 16px;
padding: 20px;
text-align: justify;
font-family: Verdana; 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal; 
color: #000;
font-size: 14px;


}


#welcome_box h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#welcome_box p {
  color: #000;
  margin: 1em 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}


#welcome_box ul {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#welcome_box li {
  list-style: square;
  margin-left: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
}



/** Main body Removals Box **/


#removals_box {

float:left; display:inline;

width: 358px;
height: 436px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
border:3px solid #696969;

-webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 6px 6px 6px;
-moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 6px 6px 6px; 
box-shadow: #B3B3B3 9px 9px 9px;

background: #CDCF6D; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #E6E87A 0%, #CDCF6D 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#E6E87A), color-stop(100%,#CDCF6D)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #E6E87A 0%,#CDCF6D 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #E6E87A 0%,#CDCF6D 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #E6E87A 0%,#CDCF6D 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #E6E87A 0%,#CDCF6D 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#E6E87A', endColorstr='#CDCF6D',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */



margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 16px;
padding: 20px;
text-align: justify;
font-family: Verdana; 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal; 
color: #000;
font-size: 14px;
}

#removals_box a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

#removals_box h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#removals_box p {
  color: #000;
  margin: 1em 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#removals_box ul {
  list-style: square;
  margin-left: 34px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#removals_box li {
  list-style: disc;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}




/** Main body Prices Box **/

#prices_box {

float:left; display:inline;

width: 358px;
height: 436px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
border:3px solid #696969;

-webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 6px 6px 6px;
-moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 6px 6px 6px; 
box-shadow: #B3B3B3 9px 9px 9px;


background: #f3f3f3; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FAADAB 0%, #E8A09E 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#FAADAB), color-stop(100%,#E8A09E)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #FAADAB 0%,#E8A09E 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #FAADAB 0%,#E8A09E 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #FAADAB 0%,#E8A09E 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #FAADAB 0%,#E8A09E 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FAADAB', endColorstr='#E8A09E',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */



margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 16px;
padding: 20px;
text-align: justify;
font-family: Verdana; 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal; 
color: #000;
font-size: 14px;
}

#prices_box a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

#prices_box h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#prices_box p {
  color: #000;
  margin: 1em 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#prices_box ul {
  list-style: disc;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#prices_box li {
  list-style: disc;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}



/** Main body Quick Quote Box **/


#quick_quote {

float:left; display:inline;
width: 358px;
height: 436px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
border:3px solid #696969;

-webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 6px 6px 6px;
-moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 6px 6px 6px; 
box-shadow: #B3B3B3 9px 9px 9px;


background: #8EC3E3; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #8EC3E3 0%, #7EADC9 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#8EC3E3), color-stop(100%,#7EADC9)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #8EC3E3 0%,#7EADC9 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #8EC3E3 0%,#7EADC9 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #8EC3E3 0%,#7EADC9 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #8EC3E3 0%,#7EADC9 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#8EC3E3', endColorstr='#7EADC9',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */


margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 16px;
padding: 20px;
text-align: left;
font-family: Verdana; 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal; 
color: #000;
font-size: 14px;
}


#quick_quote h2 {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#quick_quote p {
  color: #000;
  margin: 1em 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}


#quick_quote ul {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#quick_quote li {
  list-style: square;
  margin-left: 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
}



/** Footer **/

#footer {

padding-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana; 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal; 
font-size: 14px;
color: #464544;
padding-top: 3.5em;
padding-bottom: 2em;
margin: 0.5em 0em;
clear: both;
}

#footer a {
  color: #464544;
}

#footer a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

HTML as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title>Title</title>

        <meta name="description" content="Removals">
        <meta name="keywords" content="...">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="...">
        <meta itemprop="description" content="...">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_removals.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="images/z1-move.jpg"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="images/z2-friendly.jpg"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="images/z3-map.jpg"
var image4=new Image()
image4.src="images/z4-family.jpg"
var image5=new Image()
image5.src="images/z5-man.jpg"
var image6=new Image()
image6.src="images/z6-balloon.jpg"

//-->
</script>


</head>


<body>

<div id="container">   <!-- Start Page Container --!>

<div id="header">   <!-- Start Header --!>

<div id="logo">
<img src="images/oco_logo8.gif" width="447" height="110">
</div>

<div id="logo_text">
<p>T: XXXX XXXX<br>E: <a href="mailto:admin@XXXXX">admin@XXXXX</a></p>
</div>


</div>  <!-- End Header --!>


<div id="nav">  <!-- Start Nav --!>

<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>&nbsp&nbspHome&nbsp&nbsp</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='removals.html'><span>&nbsp&nbspRemovals & Other Services&nbsp&nbsp</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='prices.html'><span>&nbsp&nbspOur Prices&nbsp&nbsp</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='contact.html'><span>&nbsp&nbspContact&nbsp&nbsp</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>  <!-- End Nav --!>


<div id="main_content">  <!-- Start Main Content --!>


<div id="pic_box">  <!-- Start Pic_Box Section --!>

<img src="images/z1-move.jpg" name="slide" width="228" height="476" />
<script>
<!--
//variable that will increment through the images
var step=1
function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
if (step<6)
step++
else
step=1
//call function "slideit()" every 10 seconds
setTimeout("slideit()",10000)
}
slideit()
//-->
</script>

</div>  <!-- End Pic_Box section--!>





<div id="removals_box"> <!-- Start Removals Section --!>

<h2>Removals and Other Services</h2>

<p>We offer a complete service that includes packing, removals, cleaning and even unpacking. Below is a list of our most commonly requested services:</p>

<li>Home removals</li>
  <ul>
<li>Local, national and international;</li>
<li>Single Item to 5+ bed house;</li>
<li>In to or out of storage;</li>   
<li>University student moves</li>
  </ul>

<li>Office relocations</li>
<li>Full or partial packing service</li>
<li>Packing supplies</li>
<li>End of tenancy property cleaning</li>
<li>Unpacking service</li>
<li>Furniture Assembly</li>
<li>House Clearances</li>
<li>Storage Deal - Our customers receive a 5% discount at Safestore and Big Yellow</li>

<p>Simply telephone, email or complete the short form opposite for a no-obligation quote.</p> 



</div>  <!-- End Removals section--!>




<div id="quick_quote">  <!-- Start Quick Quote Section --!>

<h2>Quick Quote Form</h2>
<div class="clear"> </div>


<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="400px">
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="center">
<label for="name">Your Name* </label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="70" size="30" autofocus>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="center">
<label for="email">Email*</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="email" name="email" maxlength="100" size="30" required>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="center">
<label for="telephone">Telephone*</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="tel" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="center">
<label for="address_from">Address (From)</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="address_from" maxlength="100" size="30">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="center">
<label for="property_size">Property Size</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<select name="property_size">
                <option value="studio">studio</option>
                <option value="1_bed">1 bedroom</option>
                <option selected="2_bed">2 bedroom</option>
                <option value="3_bed">3 bedroom</option>
        <option value="4_bed">4 bedroom</option>
        <option value="5+_bed">5+ bedroom</option>
                <option value="office">office relocation</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="center">
<label for="address_to">Address (To)</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="address_to" maxlength="100" size="30">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="center">
<label for="move_date">Move Date</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="date" name="move_date" >
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td valign="top" style="padding-top: 4px">
<label for="comments">Comments</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="7" placeholder="Please add any special requirements you may have, additional info on dates, key exchanges, access issues, extra large items, additional services required etc."></textarea>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<p> * indicates a required field</>

</div>  <!-- End Quick quote section--!>

</div>  <!-- End Main Content --!>



<div id="footer"> <!-- Start Footer --!>


    Telephone: XXX
    <br>
    Email: <a href="mailto:example.com">admin@example.com</a>
    <br>
    Address: xxxx
        <br>
    <br>
    &copy; xxx 2014


</div> <!-- End Footer--!>




</div>  <!-- For Container --!>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle that just mimics the problem, or post relevant code? we're not going to go to your site and search for the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you have the same number of opening and closing DIVs in your code, and that it's otherwise valid? IE9 and earlier may be interpreting it literally while newer browsers may be giving you "the benefit of the doubt".

Comment: kennypu - code now added

Comment: BFD I have checked the opening and closing DIVs manually and through a validator. No joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not all divs are being displayed in IE 9

You have a misprint in HTML comment here and below:

```
<div id="container">   <!-- Start Page Container --!>
```

Just change all your HTML comments from:

```
<!-- ... --!>
```

to

```
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: #container is not the only one - i'll get to work on this and report back.  Thanks for the spot.

Comment: Thank you so much Pinal. I would have been here all year and not spotted that.

Comment: Novice mistake.  I've given myself 40 lashes as punishment.